Is there a way to use linux "find" and filter if specific process was the only one accessed it?
I am trying to find out a way to do incremental antivirus scan. My current approach under evaluation is using "find". You can see relevant question here: Is there a reason why I can't use find to scan modified files for viruses and malware?
Please note - the question already posted above is using modified time but I found out that clamav scans files even if it is accessed or opened not just modified.
The antivirus in question is clamav. Clamav, just like every other AV has option of on access scanning i.e. it would scan a file as soon as it's acccessed or opened. That means I have to change\use command:
find /test/ -type f -atime -1 1>./find_ctime.out 2>./find.errors
Unfortunately I cannot use clamav "On Access Scanning" feature - one reason being it's too heavy on system.
If I use "find" this is a problem I run into:

I start first scan at 12:00 midnight on 10 files.
When I use "find" next day at 12:00 midnight, I have to give start time at 12:00 midnight previous day. I cannot given start time when scan was finished to find because that would leave system vulnerable.
Problem with this approach is, it would include 10 files clamav (clamscan) accessed yesterday.
I cannot blindly exclude yesterday's list, even if access timestamp was in yesterday's scan window because that will make system vulnerable, even though chances are very small.
and the cycle will repeat next day and so on until it would include ALL files on the system.

So I wanted to exclude a file if only clamscan\clamdscan has accessed it since last scan. I used stat <filepath> and do not see any relevant field in output. I also searched in find documentation but I could not find it.
Is there a way to use linux "find" and filter if specific process was the only one accessed it?
Thanks in advance!

Unless you enabled auditing, or used inotify or similar to log it manually, there's no record of which process had opened a file in the past.

@muru this question is essentially same - only difference being this question is specifically about find capabilities.

"there's no record of which process had opened a file in the past" => find has no such capabilities.

Explain your definition of ...heavy on system I run Clam AV on a Personal NAS box with only 8GB of RAM and an older ~2Ghz intel CPU just fine with no lag, as I've got about 20 active steam games there that run perfect over the network all with ClamAV doing at least a weekly scan.  You're needlessly re-inventing the wheel, i.e., why not takeout/reconfigure what's currently blocking resources for ClamAV
